# Conversion from Hinduism to other religions

Tags: other-religions, conversion

Is conversion to other religions allowed in Hinduism? Are there any references in Vedic texts on this regard? Is it considered a sin? If so what happens to one who converts after death?

Comment: Why would it be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure you know the following two famous slokas of Gita:

> श्रेयान्स्वधर्मो विगुणः परधर्मात्स्वनुष्ठितात्।
>
> स्वधर्मे निधनं श्रेयः परधर्मो भयावहः।।3.35।।
>
> One's own 'Dharma' [Customary or scripturally ordained observances of different castes and sects.-Tr.], though defective, is superior to another's 'Dharma' well-performed. Death is better while engaged in one's own 'Dharma'; another's 'Dharma' is fraught with fear.
>
> श्रेयान्स्वधर्मो विगुणः परधर्मात्स्वनुष्ठितात्।
>
> स्वभावनियतं कर्म कुर्वन्नाप्नोति किल्बिषम्।।18.47।।
>
> 18.47 One's own 'Dharma', (though) defective, is superior to another's 'Dharma' well performed. By performing a 'Dharma' as dictated by one's own nature, one does not incur sin.

These two slokas can be broadly interpreted to understand Sri Krishna's view on conversion from any religion to other religion.

Comment: Btw the verses are about Varna Dharma and not about Dharma meaning religion :)

Comment: @Rickross yes, thats why i hv mentioned that this requires a broad interpretation.

Comment: This has nothing to do with other religions. Downvoted.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: So you are saying conversions both ways is not recommended?

Comment: @sv. yes I think Gita says so.Sri Ramakrishna also accepted all the religions as true.

Comment: Ok, can you that add that conclusion directly to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Hindus should not convert to other religions.

> Vyasa says, '..The rejection of one's own creed, the practice of other
>   people's creed, ......- these all have been pronounced by persons
>   conversant with duties to be acts that no one should do.’

*Mahabharata Santi Parva, Section XXXIV-XXXV*

Comment: I am not sure if creed is religion.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu yes Creed does mean religion. You'll find the meaning for it in Wikipedia. a system of religious belief; a faith.

Comment: I did not know any word exists in sanskrit that can be translated to 'religion' or 'creed'.This is addition to my knowledge.What is the sanskrit word that has been translated as 'creed' by the way?

Comment: @partha true that. I take back my first line. What I meant was that Creed is translated as religion in Wikipedia. Maybe this definition is true for other religions, but I do not know in context of Hinduism, for it is more than just a religion. To me it is a way of life, but it's one thing to use a Sanskrit word and another to find an exact translation in the English language.

Comment: @Hemambujavalli thanks.my question was addressed to the op as he quoted only the translation.

Comment: Can the same reference ("no one should do the practice of other people's creed") be applied to non-Hindus who want to convert to Hinduism?

Answer (score -1):

That what can be called as "other religions" is considered to be a heresy, and it is not allowed.

[Manu-smriti](https://archive.org/details/lawsofmanu00bh/page/380) 9.225 says:

> Gamblers, dancers and singers, cruel men, **men belonging to an heretical sect**, those following forbidden occupations, and sellers of spirituous liquor, let him instantly banish from his town.

In the next verse 226 those persons are called "secret thieves":

> If such (persons who are) **secret thieves**, dwell in the realm of a king, they constantly harass his good subjects by their forbidden practices.